# What is the use of outputStreaming in SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security-oauth2, outputstream, spring-web

I am using `OAuth2RestTemplate` class of `spring-security-oauth2-2.1.1.RELEASE` for rest client services. Ideally, whenever an access token expires, the template should retry the failed request by fetching the new access token. But at times, when an access token is expired on post requests, the template is exiting with the following error:

> org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "REQUEST-URL": cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode; nested exception is java.net.HttpRetryException: cannot retry due to server authentication, in streaming mode

Upon searching, I got to know that this behavior is due to the `outputStreaming` variable of `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` and this is set to true by default. I tried to set this variable to false and everything works fine. But I am not aware of what happens if set `outputStreaming` variable to false. So I am trying to understand it's purpose which helps me in deciding whether should I go ahead disabling the `outputStreaming`.

Thanks in advance!